# Ordenar una lista circular doblemente enlazada alfabéticamente JAVA

Tags: java

Deseo saber cómo **ordenar una lista circular doblemente enlazada alfabéticamente**, de forma `ascendente` y `descendente` por método de inserción o burbuja.
La lista que tengo almacena el objeto cancion, y deseo ordenar la lista por medio del título de la canción cancion.gettitle()

```
public static void ordenAscendente(Lista lista){
        if(lista.getTamano()>1){
            for(int i=0;i<lista.getTamano();i++){
                Nodo actual=lista.getCabeza();
                Nodo siguiente=lista.getCabeza().getSiguiente();
                String l1=actual.getCancion().getTitulo();
                String l2=siguiente.getCancion().getTitulo();

                for(int j=0; j<lista.getTamano()-1;j++){
                    if(comparacion(l1,l2)>0){
                        Nodo aux=actual;
                        actual=siguiente;
                        siguiente=aux;
                    }
                    actual=siguiente;
                    siguiente=siguiente.getSiguiente();
                    lista.imprimir();
                }
            }
        }   

    }
    public static int comparacion(String p1,String p2){
        int l1=p1.length();
        int l2=p2.length();
        int lmin=Math.min(l1, l2);

        for(int i=0; i<lmin;i++){
                int stgr_1=(int)p1.charAt(i);
                int stgr_2=(int)p2.charAt(i);
                if(stgr_1 != stgr_2){
                    return stgr_1-stgr_2;
                }
            }
        if(l1 != l2){
            return l1-l2;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Poseo este código, pero no realiza ningún ordenamiento.

Comment: Las preguntas que no tienen un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), terminan cerradas. Te recomiendo que agregues en la pregunta el código que tengas hecho hasta ahora, aquí se resuelve dudas especificas, no tareas ni deberes.

Comment: Tienes la razón. Edité la pregunta, agregando el código que poseo en mi clase de ordenamiento. Mi duda es, ¿por qué no funciona?

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas reinventar la rueda? ¿No puedes usar el método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))?

Comment: En fin, si es un práctica, debes hacer que el método de ordenamiento tenga un parámetro de tipo [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). De este modo, puedes definir un criterio de ordenamiento y así reutilizar código y usas un mismo método para ordenar de forma ascendente, descendente, alfabéticamente, entre otros y la ventaja de hacerlo así, es que tú mismo decides que atributo de un objeto debes ordenar.

Answer (score -1):

Cada vez que se repite el procedimiento de comparación, hay que redefinir los Strings

```java
public static void ordenAscendente(Lista lista){
        if(lista.getTamano()>1){
            for(int i=0;i<lista.getTamano();i++){
                Nodo actual=lista.getCabeza();
                Nodo siguiente=lista.getCabeza().getSiguiente();
                for(int j=0; j<lista.getTamano()-1;j++){
                  String l1=actual.getCancion().getTitulo();
                  String l2=siguiente.getCancion().getTitulo();

                    if(comparacion(l1,l2)>0){
                        Nodo aux=actual;
                        actual=siguiente;
                        siguiente=aux;
                    }
                    actual=siguiente;
                    siguiente=siguiente.getSiguiente();
                    lista.imprimir();
                }
            }
        }   

    }
    public static int comparacion(String p1,String p2){
        int l1=p1.length();
        int l2=p2.length();
        int lmin=Math.min(l1, l2);

        for(int i=0; i<lmin;i++){
                int stgr_1=(int)p1.charAt(i);
                int stgr_2=(int)p2.charAt(i);
                if(stgr_1 != stgr_2){
                    return stgr_1-stgr_2;
                }
            }
        if(l1 != l2){
            return l1-l2;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Esa comparación está hecha a pedal y bien podrías, como te indican en los comentarios a la pregunta, usar Comparator para esta tarea y el método completo sería innecesario